# Password Protect SSRS reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have several reports delivered via email in PDF and Excel formats.  I am looking for ways to password protect these items, either natively via SSRS or using a process outside of SSRS.

Comment: Can you not use the built in security / authentication that comes with SSRS already?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the built-in authentication provided by reporting services, you have one other option.  First things first though, you cannot use the "E-mail" based subscription and interfere with that process to encrypt a pdf file.  The only way to do this is to use the file share delivery method.

Deliver the report to a network folder and then use Adobe's web service API to protect the PDF as outlined here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/sdkHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=sdkHelp&file=quickStarts_Encryption.8.3.html

Once you do that you would have to write an app that takes the PDF and attaches it to an e-mail.